How to use jq to create a JSON object with path-value pairs (instead of key-value pairs)?
In jq scripts, I needed to create json objects using pairs of path-values (which are more general than the old key-value pairs). That is, instead of a key, I need to use a path, so that the value is created at a deeper level. (These paths are given externally, so I don't know them in advance.)
For example, in non-working pseudo-code, I'd like to use paths to create an object like this:
jq -n '{"a"."x" : 3, "b"."y" : 4}'

so that it creates the same json object as jq -n '{"a":{"x" : 3}, "b":{"y" : 4}}', i.e.
{
  "a": {
    "x": 3
  },
  "b": {
    "y": 4
  }
}

In a way, this is similar to mdir -p which allows one to directly create a target directory with all the ancestor-directories along the path. But I need to do this for (many) json objects. Hence, the question:
What is the simplest way of object creation by path-value pairs using native jq (maybe plus some bash)?
(I am looking for low-complexity a solution without serious programming. This is with jq-1.7.1. under Ubuntu 24.04 LTS)
-- Clarification --
The input I have in mind is a list of paths plus a list of values, such as:
[".a.x", ".b.y"] 

and
[3, 4]

. The path is separated by dots. For simplicity, I assume each part between the dots is a simple identifier such as y (not a complex one such as "y.z"). That is, I do not consider (for now) paths such as:
[".a.x", ".b.\"y.z\""]


$ jq -n '.a.x = 3 | .b.y = 4'
{
  "a": {
    "x": 3
  },
  "b": {
    "y": 4
  }
}

The jq expression first sets the x key beneath a to 3, and the resulting object is passed on via the pipe to another similar assignment, setting the y key of b to 4 in the same object.
However, this uses the static paths .a.x and .b.y.
Would you want to work with data given from the shell, then you could do the following for your two values:
jq -n --argjson value 3 'setpath($ARGS.positional; $value)' --args a x |
jq    --argjson value 4 'setpath($ARGS.positional; $value)' --args b y

This uses setpath() to set the path given by the list at the end of the command line (a and x in the first instance) to the value given to the $value variable.  The result is then passed on to a similar jq invocation that adds a second value at another path (note the lack of -n here, though!) If the value should be added as a string (not a number), then use --arg in place of --argjson when you give the value.
The result of this pipeline would be
{
  "a": {
    "x": 3
  },
  "b": {
    "y": 4
  }
}

Depending on what form you have the path on in the shell, you might find it useful to pass a fully constructed path array to jq:
jq -n --argjson path '["a","x"]' --argjson value 3 'setpath($path; $value)' |
jq    --argjson path '["b","y"]' --argjson value 4 'setpath($path; $value)'

If you have the paths in the form .a.x and .b.y, then you can split these up with split() to form path arrays for setpath():
jq -n --arg path .a.x --argjson value 3 'setpath($path|split(".")[1:]; $value)' |
jq    --arg path .b.y --argjson value 4 'setpath($path|split(".")[1:]; $value)'

The [1:] on the result of split() is needed only if your path strings start with a dot. Note that this is the first variation of this solution that doesn't allow dots in key names.

With your clarified input taken into consideration, you may use
jq -n --argjson path '[".a.x", ".b.y"]' --argjson value '[3,4]' '[ ([$path,$value]|transpose[]) as [$p,$v] | setpath($p|split(".")[1:];$v) ] | add'

This first creates a single $p ("path") and $v ("value") pair from each combined element of the two arrays $path and $value.  The $p string is then split in a similar manner as before, and the value $v is assigned to it with setpath().
The only "magic" here is the initial [$path,$value] | transpose[], which generates the two arrays
[".a.x",3]
[".b.y",4]

... and the fact that the whole operation takes place within an array constructor, forming the array
[
  {
    "a": {
      "x": 3
    }
  },
  {
    "b": {
      "y": 4
    }
  }
]

... which add then combines into our final product:
{
  "a": {
    "x": 3
  },
  "b": {
    "y": 4
  }
}

Again, dots are not allowed in key strings, and we also assume that the input arrays' length will always be the same.

@tinlyx you'll have to add some more constraints to the question. mkdir doesn't have to worry about the path separator / appearing in a directory name, but .a."x.y" is a reasonable jq path for {"a": {"x.y": ...}}

@muru yes, but the idea is pretty simple without reference to mkdir. If I can use p as a path in a jq expression, can it somehow be used as a (composite) key?  Please see the added clarification.
